# C# infinite iteration

Tags: c#, .net, linq, enumerable

Is there anything similar in C# to Java's `Stream.iterate`? The closest thing I could find was `Enumerable.Range` but it is much different.

The reason I'm asking is that I've been just watching some [presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=3G-LO9T3D1M#t=38224) about good programming principles and there was a thread about declarative vs. imperative code. What caught my attention was a way you can generate a pseudo-infinite set of data.

Answer (score 13):

There isn't an exact equivalent in the .Net framework but there is one in the [MoreLINQ library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/1.1.0):

```
foreach (var current in MoreEnumerable.Generate(5, n => n + 2).Take(10))
{
    Console.WriteLine(current);
}
```

It's also very simple to recreate it using `yield`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Iterate<T>(T seed, Func<T,T> unaryOperator)
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return seed;
        seed = unaryOperator(seed);
    }
}
```

`yield` enables to create an infinite enumerator because:

> When a yield return statement is reached in the iterator method, expression is returned, and the current location in code is retained. Execution is restarted from that location the next time that the iterator function is called.

From [yield (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx)

Comment: I actually didn't want to write new extension method.

Comment: @SOReader Then use MoreLINQ.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer here. It provides a clear answer (which is "no, there isn't") while also providing a very common alternative in the `MoreLinq` library as well as handcrafted code to achieve it without the library.