# What is the equivalent of iterate function in haskell in c#?

Tags: c#, haskell

We have iterate function in haskell Prelude

```
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
iterate f x == [x, f x, f (f x), ...]
```

What is the equivalent in C#?

Comment: Afaik there is no method with that functionality, but you can of course write one yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't one but you can write your own:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Iterate<T>(T seed, Func<T, T> step)
{
    while(true)
    {
        yield return seed;
        seed = step(seed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great minds [think alike?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26802910/5743988)